# async validation reactive forms angular with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

I need to validate if the user exists in the state of my application. In my application I'm using ngrx and through a selector I want to validate if the user exists.

**How can I do this?**

I'm not able to validate this way, what am I doing wrong?

```
return this._formBuilder.group({
  id: ['', this._existUser()],
  dateStart: ['', Validators.required],
  dateEnd: ['', Validators.required]
})

  private _existUser(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<{ [key: string]: any } | null> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
      const userId = control.value;
      return this._store.select(usersSelectors.getUserById, { id: userId}).pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        take(1),
        map(value => {
          // Not entering the map...
          return !!value ? { invalid: true } : null;
        })
      )
    };
  }
```

**selectors.ts:**

```
export const getUserById = createSelector(
    selectEntities,
    (entities, props): any => {
        return entities[props.id];
    }
);
```

Comment: is the validator called? is your selector working?

Comment: Yes it is being called, and the selector works when I do subscribe.

Comment: I think its because this._existUser() is an async validator and should passed as the third argument

Comment: That was the problem, can you post here the solution for me to place as resolved? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined this._existUser() as second parameter which is for validators or options, async-validators have to be passed as third parameter

```
return this._formBuilder.group({
  id: ['', [], this._existUser()],
  dateStart: ['', Validators.required],
  dateEnd: ['', Validators.required]
})
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl